# Swap columns of specific rows in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to swap columns of specific rows (`where y==1`) of np.array.
The code works properly if the `idc_fail` does not contain only zeros or ones. But I don't understand why. Thanks in advance!

```
X = np.random.rand(3,2)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 1))
print(X)
print(y)

idc_fail = np.where(y == 1)

X[idc_fail,[0, 1]] = X[idc_fail,[1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using boolean selection?

```
idx = y[:,0].astype(bool)      # or idx = y[:,0] == 1
# array([False,  True, False])

X[idx] = X[idx, ::-1]          # or X[idx, [0,1]] = X[idx, [1,0]]
```

Example:

```
# input
array([[0.5488135 , 0.71518937],
       [0.60276338, 0.54488318],
       [0.4236548 , 0.64589411]])

# output
array([[0.5488135 , 0.71518937],
       [0.54488318, 0.60276338],
       [0.4236548 , 0.64589411]])
```

Comment: unfortunately it also does not work if idx: array([True,  True, True])

Comment: @Lorenzooo what means "doesn't work"? For me it swaps all values, which seems expected no?

Comment: ---> 12 X[idxx_fail,[0, 1]] = X[idxx_fail,[1, 0]]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)